# Git : git rm delete the file both locally and as well as in remote repository

Tags: git

I have a master and development branch .
I did some commits to the development branch and did a push to the remote  repository as shown

```
git checkout development
git rm AbstractContent.java 
git push -u origin development .
```

I observed  `git rm AbstractContent.java  command`  the file got deleted locally , but inside remote repository it is still present .

**Please let me know how can i delete the file both locally and as well as in remote repository .**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commit before you push.

```
git rm AbstractContent.java 
git commit -m "Remove AbstractContent"
git push -u origin development
```