# Delete Files from Git

Tags: git

I have just started to use git today.

I have a repository in `project_master/project` folder.
I made that with `git init --bare`.

Then, I `cd` to `project_work`, and `git clone ../project_master/project`

I did some changes to the repository in `project_work/project`. Type `make test`. Didn't type `make clean`. After that, I `git add` everything, `git commit`, and `git push origin master`.

Now all the `.o`, `.a` files of the unit tests get into the repository in `project_master/project` folder. How to delete those `.o`, `.a` files from the repository in `project_master/project` folder?

Thank you.

Update:

I did the following:

```
~/project_work/project
cd unit_test
git rm *.o
git commit
git push origin master
```

Then,

```
cd ~/project_test
rm -rf project
rm -rf .git
ls -a
git clone ../project_master/project
cd project/unit_test
```

And the `.o` files are still there.

I also did as in this SO question: [Completely remove files from Git repo and remote on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563564/completely-remove-files-from-git-repo-and-remote-on-github). But didn't work. After that, I try `git rm` again and that didn't work.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174757/git-git-rm-delete-the-file-both-locally-and-as-well-as-in-remote-repository

Comment: But do you need to be removing everytime it or just for now?

Comment: It depends if you want to purge their history, or just remove them from the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common approaches:

#### 1. Remove locally then update git

```
rm filename(s)
git add -u .
git commit
git push
```

#### 2. Use git itself to remove the file

```
git rm filename(s)
git commit
git push
```

End result is the same, second approach is easier to use.

Comment: strange. the 2nd method now works too, and it didn't say Everything up-to-date this time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rm *.o` to stage their removal from git. Then use `git commit` to create the commit to remove them, or `git commit --amend` to amend the last commit that added these files and remove them from it.

Comment: I did that before asking this question. After that I clone the repository in `project_master/project` to a folder call `project_test`. I found that those .a files are still there. After I type those commands. I typed git push origin master. and also git push. both commands says Everything up-to-date.

Comment: You need to `git push` before that commit will be in your `project_master` repository.

Comment: Also, these types of files should go in a [`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), which is normally committed to the root folder of your repository.

Comment: will definitely try gitignore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the helpful comments.